# MediaSessionCompat_OnActiveChangeListenerImplementor error after Migrating to Android X in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, androidx

I have migrated my Xamarin.Android to **Android X** in Xamarin Forms. After migrating I got several issues and closed them one by one. I got stuck with below issue where I couldn't able to resolve it.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): Error XA4215: The Java type `mono.android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat_OnActiveChangeListenerImplementor` is generated by more than one managed type. Please change the [Register] attribute so that the same Java type is not emitted. (XA4215) (EmployeeApp.Droid)

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): Error XA4215:   `mono.android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat_OnActiveChangeListenerImplementor` generated by: Android.Support.V4.Media.Session.MediaSessionCompat+IOnActiveChangeListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null (XA4215) (EmployeeApp.Droid)

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): Error XA4215:   `mono.android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat_OnActiveChangeListenerImplementor` generated by: Android.Support.V4.Media.Session.MediaSessionCompat+IOnActiveChangeListenerImplementor, Xamarin.AndroidX.Media, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null (XA4215) (EmployeeApp.Droid)
```

I tried several approaches mentioned in Android X github
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/issues/71 but still I am facing this issue.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.